# Horizontal to vertical display using Dynamic Pivot Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a one to many mapping table displayed as below. I need to display the `ICD10` HORIZONTALLY.
for each `ICD9`. The data is dynamic hence I cannot use the static pivot function.

```
ICD9 | ICD10
-----+------
0156 | 0178
0156 | 0179
0123 | 0181
0152 | 0202
0231 | 0210
0231 | 0211
0231 | 0212
```

I want the result to be displayed as-

```
ICD9 | ICD10 | ICD10 | ICD10
0156 | 0178  | 0179  | null
0123 | 0181  | null  | null
0152 | 0202  | null  | null
0231 | 0210  | 0211  | 0212
```

Currently I tried to use this code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(icd10) 
            FROM mv_icd
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT icd9, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select icd9,icd10 from mv_icd
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(icd9)
                for icd10 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
            execute(@query)
```

but it does not work as I have too many records (about 12000). How can I alter the code to display the `ICD10` for each `ICD9` in a column?

Comment: If you are trying to pivot 12000 columns, you won't be able to.  I'd suggest looking at doing something inside your application instead of in SQL.  What's the max number of `icd10` that you will have for each `icd9`?

Answer (score 5):

Based on your current code, you are converting all 12000 values in the `ICD10` column into new columns.  That is far too many columns and completely unmanageable for any user.

It appears that you really want to convert each `ICD10` value associated with `ICD9` into new columns.  To do this, you'll need to use a windowing function like `row_number()` and create a unique value for each `ICD10` that will be used as the new column names.

Your query will using something like:

```
select icd9, icd10,
  rn = row_number() over(partition by icd9 order by icd10)
from mv_icd
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b86a8/13). This gives a result:

```
| ICD9 | ICD10 | RN |
|------|-------|----|
|  123 |   181 |  1 |
|  152 |   202 |  1 |
|  156 |   178 |  1 |
|  156 |   179 |  2 |
|  231 |   210 |  1 |
|  231 |   211 |  2 |
|  231 |   212 |  3 |
```

You now have a new column `rn` that contains the number of `ICD10` values for each `ICD9`.  This new column will be used in the pivot to create your new columns.  If you have a limited number of columns, then you can hard code the query:

```
select icd9, [1], [2], [3]
from 
(
  select icd9, icd10,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by icd9 order by icd10)
  from mv_icd
) d
pivot
(
  max(icd10)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b86a8/14).  Now if you don't know how many total `ICD10` items you'd have for each `ICD9` you'll have to use dynamic SQL.  You'd alter your code in your original query to be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- get list of the unique # of ICD10's per ICD9
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(rn) 
            FROM
            (
              SELECT rn = row_number() over(partition by icd9 order by icd10)
              FROM mv_icd
            ) d
            GROUP BY rn
            ORDER BY rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
       = 'SELECT icd9, ' + @cols + ' 
          from 
          (
            select icd9, icd10,
              rn = row_number() over(partition by icd9 order by icd10)
            from mv_icd
           ) x
           pivot 
           (
             max(icd10)
             for rn in (' + @cols + ')
           ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b86a8/15). These give a final result of:

```
| ICD9 |   1 |      2 |      3 |
|------|-----|--------|--------|
|  123 | 181 | (null) | (null) |
|  152 | 202 | (null) | (null) |
|  156 | 178 |    179 | (null) |
|  231 | 210 |    211 |    212 |
```

Now you can alter the names of the final columns to whatever you need, but this should give you the result that you want without creating 12000 columns.